# Document Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have node js running a server that loads an html file with express. This html file has javascript that hides and shows a picture on the page with a button. I want to use the same function to hide  and show the picture without the need for a button by calling the method in the main.js file that contains the rest of the application code. However, whenever I call the method it gives me a document not defined error. The button that calls the same function when clicked works however. I am not sure what the problem is (new to node).

web.js:

```
const hider = require("./public/script");

function site(){
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');

    const port = 3000;

    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server Started on: 127.0.0.1:"+port));
};

function hidePic(){
    hider.hide();
}


module.exports = { site , hidePic}
```

File loaded by express. The button to hide the image works.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="hide()">Try it</button>

    <div id="picture1">
        <img src="img.jpg" alt="img">
    </div> 

    <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

script.js:

```
function hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("picture1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
}

module.exports = { hide }
```

Main program

main.js:

```
const web = require("./website")

web.site();

web.hidePic(); //Want this to hide picture in on webserver from within this file
```

Comment: because the server has no relationship to the clientside.

Comment: `document` only exists once the page is rendered in the client's browser. Serverside node.js generates the HTML but has no access to the client.

Comment: so its not possible to do something similar to what I want?

Comment: You can do that by calling the code inside onload callback on body or equivalent. Just like you have called the function on button onclick, you can write something like <body onload="hide()"> ... </body> - this will work.

Comment: How would I unhide when sometthing happens in the main.js